# C# append test with StringBuilder

Tags: c#, newline, stringbuilder

I create a long text using StringBuilder but I would like just new line character '\n' (Unix mode)  instead of '\r\n', then I would write the whole text in a file.

I tried to insert '\n' character between lines and set AppendFormat method but useless.

Maybe I split this long text along the '\n' character and I write these lines out in file separately.

```
    string rowStart = "\n*****" + from + "|" + to;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(data[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        //sb.AppendFormat("\n{0}", rowStart + data[i]); not work
        sb.Append(rowStart + data[i]);
    }
    //var t = sb.Replace("\r\n","\n"); not work
    return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: @SandoorHatvani please show us your written code so we can help you

Comment: Did you try `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: before write the text to file, replace all '\r' into '' should work. imho

Comment: @scegg i think this will work for windows

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in your output? You are wanting a string that can be written to file that has new line characters as '\n' rather than '\r\n', am I correct in thinking that? And if that is true is that a constant requirement regardless of the environment you are running in? Also it would useful to see the code of what you have tried

Comment: Thanks for the code... another request... what do you mean by 'not work'? are you opening this in a text editor and not seeing line breaks? if so what text editor on what OS?

Comment: Thx but Environment.NewLine add OS new line character. Windows uses '\r\n', but I want '\n'.

Comment: Yes, I open the file with Notepad++ and there are CRLF signs at the end of every line.

Comment: The task to create a long text then to write into a file only with the new line '\n' character but StringBuilder append method use the CRLF.

Comment: @SándorHatvani have you tried Ananke solution? What makes you think Notepad++ does not replace LF with CRFL when file is opened?

Comment: If I write the lines one by one into a file then I open it in Notepad++ just LF characters are at the end of the lines. I think Notepad++ dosen't replace it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StringBuilder.AppendLine just does the following:

```
public StringBuilder AppendLine(string value)
{
    this.Append(value);
    return this.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

As Environment.NewLine cannot be set you are left with either doing two appends, or writing your own extension method, for example:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void AppendUnixLine(this StringBuilder builder, string s)
    {
        builder.Append(s);
        builder.Append('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but there are yet CRLF characters at the end of the lines.

Comment: I'm sorry, it turned out that the service what I have to use modifies the line brake sign. Thank you very much for all of you.